# Serving static content from a jarfile with Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, jruby

This should be fairly easy, but for some reason nearly everything I try just seems to hand out a 'not found' error when I hook it up to a web browser.

I've got a single static context, and for the ResourceBase I've got 'file:jar:/path/to/myjar!/.'... any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try to load the resource from classloader like this,

```
    ClassLoader classLoader =
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        if (classLoader == null) {
            classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        }


        InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(name);
```

Your approach assumes absolute path and it may not be true when the server is deployed. The jar could be in another JAR (WAR) or a temporary directory.

Comment: I can readily change the path later, I'm just seeing if I can get this to work at all, and I'm not loading a servlet from the JAR -- just static .html files.

Comment: I don't think your syntax is right. It should be,

jar:file:/path/to/my.jar!/package/file

If this is on Windows, you might also need the drive letter.